# QBO API V3 : Product Inventory is not getting updated

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We want to manually adjust/update the Inventory of an Item using QBO V3 API.
But, the QtyOnHand did not get updated on QBO properly. We re-checked using QBO browser app too.

1. First Request : Create a product of type "Inventory" on QBO with "QtyOnHand" set to 100.
   a. The response appropriately mentioned that the product is created.
2. Second Request : Update the above product with "QtyOnHand" set to 200.
   b. The response still contains the older QtyOnHand (100). It didn't reflect that new QtyOnHand.

How can we manually adjust / update QtyOnHand using QBO V3 API?

For reference, our update request is:

```
<IntuitBatchRequest xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <BatchItemRequest operation="update" bId="0">
        <Item>
            <Id>2091</Id>
            <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
            <Name>Product 26--var 2</Name>
            <Description>false</Description>
            <Taxable>true</Taxable>
            <UnitPrice>1000.00</UnitPrice>
            <Type>Inventory</Type>
            <IncomeAccountRef>62</IncomeAccountRef>
            <ExpenseAccountRef>111</ExpenseAccountRef>
            <AssetAccountRef>112</AssetAccountRef>
            <TrackQtyOnHand>true</TrackQtyOnHand>
            <QtyOnHand>200</QtyOnHand>
            <InvStartDate>2014-01-21</InvStartDate>
        </Item>
    </BatchItemRequest>
</IntuitBatchRequest>
```

Our response XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-01-20T23:21:44.559-08:00">
   <BatchItemResponse bId="0">
      <Item domain="QBO" sparse="false">
         <Id>2091</Id>
         <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
         <MetaData>
            <CreateTime>2014-01-20T22:44:10-08:00</CreateTime>
            <LastUpdatedTime>2014-01-20T22:44:10-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>
         </MetaData>
         <Name>Product 26--var 2</Name>
         <Description>false</Description>
         <Active>true</Active>
         <FullyQualifiedName>Product 26--var 2</FullyQualifiedName>
         <Taxable>true</Taxable>
         <UnitPrice>1000</UnitPrice>
         <Type>Inventory</Type>
         <IncomeAccountRef name="Sales">62</IncomeAccountRef>
         <PurchaseCost>0</PurchaseCost>
         <ExpenseAccountRef name="Cost of Goods Sold">111</ExpenseAccountRef>
         <AssetAccountRef name="Inventory Asset">112</AssetAccountRef>
         <TrackQtyOnHand>true</TrackQtyOnHand>
         <QtyOnHand>100</QtyOnHand>
         <InvStartDate>2014-01-21</InvStartDate>
      </Item>
   </BatchItemResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `QtyOnHand` field is not an update-able field.

Inventory adjustments are made when:

- You create a transaction that uses up inventory (Sales Receipts, Invoices, etc.)
- You create a transaction that returns inventory (Credit Memos)
- You issue an Inventory Adjustment (unfortunately, Intuit's API does not support this yet)

Given that the API does not support inventory adjustments yet, I don't think you'll be able to do what you're trying to do.